# ¿Cómo puedo en Flutter crear ítems para una ListView a partir de un String compuesto por palabras divididas por un \n?

Tags: json, string, flutter, listview

Necesito llenar una ListView en flutter a partir de un archivo JSON, el cual contiene un String compuesto por muchas palabras separadas por un salto de línea `\n`. Mi idea es que cada palabra pueda ser un ítem independiente en la ListView para trabajar con ellas más adelante.

Aquí el código hasta el momento:

String en cuestión: `[{ "Datos":"1 negro\n2blanco\n2verde\n2amarillo\n2rojo\n2azul\n" }]`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              var newData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 32, bottom: 32, left: 16, right: 16),
                    child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                     Text(newData[index]['Datos'],
                     style: const TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 16,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                     textAlign: TextAlign.justify,),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                //  itemCount: newData == null ? 0 : newData.length, /// ok
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo directamente en el futureBuilder o como yo prefiero, hacer un método aparte y cargar los datos en el `initState`
Primero creamos una variable que va a guardar la lista de String:

```
List<String> jsonWords = [];
```

Y también una variable booleana para mostar un cargando mientras llenamos la lista:

```
bool loading = false;
```

personalmente yo creo un método donde recojo la data:

```
Future<void> getJsonData() async {
//con esta variable booleana puedes mostar un cargando en pantalla mientras generas la lista de palabras
setState(() => loading = true);

//en tu caso usa esta línea de código
/*final json =
    await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data.json');*/

//en mi caso uso esta:
final json = [
  {"Datos": "1negro\n2blanco\n2verde\n2amarillo\n2rojo\n2azul\n"}
];

final jsnEncode = jsonEncode(json);

final decode = jsonDecode(jsnEncode);
final data = decode[0]["Datos"];

//separamos la cadena string siempre y cuando haya un "\n"
final split = data.toString().split("\n");

//hacemos un ciclo para poder ingresar cada palabra en una lista
for (var word in split) {
  listWords.add(word);
}

//eliminamos el último elemento que es un salto de línea vacío
setState(() => listWords.remove(listWords.last));
//debugPrint("datos: $data");

//con esto ya tienes una lista de palabras

//dejas de mostrar el cargando cuando ya has generado la lista
setState(() => loading = false);
```

}

Esto también lo puedes poner dentro del FutureBuilder sin problema.

Si lo pones dentro del FutureBuilder omite esta parte.
Luego en el `initState` llamamos al método para que se inicialice antes de dibujar los widget y muestre el cargando en pantalla:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getJsonData();
  }
```

Y ya por último puedes agregar esta lista a tu `ListView.builder`:

```
    Expanded(
        child: loading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listJson.length,
                itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Text(listJson[index]),
                  );
                }))
```

Comment: Eres un Genio!!! muchas gracias funciona perfecto!

Comment: De nada, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides de marcarla como aceptada, para que otras personas con problemas similares puedan verla como ayuda